# Furigana fontsize unaffected by \rubysize

Tags: fontsize, platex

I am new to platex and ruby, and to using *TeX for typesetting Japanese in general. I am currently trying to translate a novel I have been working on into Japanese, and wanted to use furigana when translating non-dictionary words from the source into Japanese. However, no matter what I do to \rubysize, the furigana remains approximately the same size as the main text itself, leading to all sorts of difficulties with spacing and overlap:

[image: How it renders]

I am providing my header so that if there are any obvious errors in my setup hopefully someone can point them out.

```
% arara: platex
%\documentclass{ltjbook}
\documentclass{jbook}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,letterpaper]{geometry}
\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
\usepackage[japanese]{babel}
%\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{verse}
%\usepackage{luatexja}
%\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.4}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.3ex}
\begin{document}
```

The comments are just packages and settings that I couldn't work out how to use properly, so ignoring them is probably best.

EDIT: Upon suggestion, here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{jbook}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,letterpaper]{geometry}
\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
\usepackage[japanese]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.4}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.3ex}
\begin{document}

\ruby{嵐}{あらし}

\end{document}
```

which leads to

[image: result]

Comment: Please post a full document which we can copy-paste to reproduce your exact problem.  This is known as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CJK package is completely incompatible with pLaTeX-style font selection scheme. It destroys size changing of Japanese characters, so please don't use it.

The command `\ruby` provided by `pxrubrica` or `okumacro` package is compatible and even better than CJK package. An example with `pxrubrica`:

```
\documentclass{jbook}
\usepackage{pxrubrica}
\begin{document}

\ruby{嵐}{あらし}

\end{document}
```

The package pxrubrica provides a lot of features required for ruby in Japanese typesetting. See pxrubrica.pdf for detail.

Comment: I'm a current maintainer of platex, and I tried to support CJK package but it failed. Some people may think that it's possible, but pTeX engine tries to translate “as much input characters as possible” into Japanese fonts; it means that the result is almost always far from acceptable, because some Chinese characters are printed in Japanese kanji variant, and vice versa. I mean, “CJK package cannot be used with pLaTeX because of limitations in the implementation of pTeX engine and some compatibility issue.”